# Totally delete the toggle button that hides and display sidebar in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How can I totally delete the toggle button that hides and display sidebar in shiny dashboard?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = T
  ),
  dashboardBody(

    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

css <- ".sidebar-toggle {display: none;}"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = T
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css)))
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```